# Able to get JSON data, but not showing up in Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, api, handlebars.js

I have the following in my page, ready to:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#athletes}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/athletes}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
```

and the following JavaScript firing below:

```
var source   = $("#some-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = $.getJSON("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/athletes?apikey=axfy7dvwqzktu28srdjna8ta", function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');          
});

$("#result").html(template(data));
```

I get an alert that the load was performed and I can see all the data in Firebug, but the #result div does not display the data.

If I replace var data with straight text as below it all functions exactly right:

```
var data = { athletes: [
    {firstName: "Josh", lastName: "Hamilton"},
    {firstName: "Yu", lastName: "Darvish"},
    {firstName: "Ian", lastName: "Kinsler"}
  ] }
```

The "athletes" key is a couple layers down in the JSON tree (sports -> leagues -> athletes). What am I not understanding about how to extract this data from the API result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball/mlb/athletes?apikey=axfy7dvwqzktu28srdjna8ta", function(data) {
      alert('Load was performed.');
      $("#result").html(template(data.sports[0].leagues[0].athletes));          
});
```

Also, an important sidenote: You have pasted your apikey. I think you would like to keep that private.

Comment: I get a "data.sports is undefined" error in the Firebug consolse

Comment: Where you able to solve this. I myself am trying to get an external json data to render my handlebars templates. Thank you

Comment: Should be $("#result").html(template(data.sports[0].leagues[0])); without the .athletes part

Answer (score 1):

You're using $.getJSON wrong. It doesn't return the data, but rather calls the success function (where you're alerting I believe) and passes the data to that. Move your html population into the success callback.

It does this because AJAX requests are asynchronous in nature by default

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean. Because $("#result").html(template(data)); will have already run before the data is loaded.

I tried that, however, and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you're can't change your `$.get()` to `$.getJSON()`, you'll have to `JSON.parse(theData)` in your success callback or the template will have no data to render. (Obvious now, but took me a moment when I had that situation.)